# JavaScript anonymous function variable

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm working on a PhoneGap app and I have this piece of code in a loop

```
htmlR += "html code here";
tx.executeSql('SELECT Question,Grp from KnowSelf where Dimension = "'+result.Dimension+'"', [], function(tx,resultR){

    var leng = resultR.rows.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < leng; i++){
        var resultsR = resultR.rows.item(i);
        htmlR += '<li class="catsli">'+resultsR.Question+'</li>';
        htmlR += '<li class="line"><img class="line" src="iPhone3/Line.png" alt="line"/></li>';

    }

},errorCB);
htmlR += "continue html code here";
```

My problem is, inside the `tx.executeSql(.... htmlR +=` `li` tags

is not adding to the outer `htmlR`.

Comment: It should be, the function you're passing into `executeSql` is a [closure](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) over it and I don't see it being [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) anywhere. Are you sure the callback accepted by `executeSql` happens synchronously? Sounds like it may be async, hence your not seeing the results immediately.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I strongly assume that it's async; otherwise, it wouldn't need a callback.

Comment: @SLaks: I expect so, but it's not the *only* reason for one. :-)

Comment: You guys are right, it is async. Anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `executeSQL` doesn't call the callback immediately, but rather *asynchronously*, and so you don't see the results immediately. If so, the correct way to handle it is to do all of your processing that relies on the results from *within* the callback, rather than after calling `executeSQL`. E.g., change:

```
// Do Something
doSomething();

// Do some SQL
executeSQL(..., function() {
   // ...deal with callback...
});

// Do something after SQL
doSomethingElse();
```

to

```
// Do Something
doSomething();

// Do some SQL
executeSQL(..., function() {
   // ...deal with callback...

    // Do something after SQL
    doSomethingElse();
});
```

Comment: Although you're solution  made sense, it does not work in my case. But thanks for the async tip, i will just change my logic